# nested routes react router dom, within layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i am building a react app using react router dom v4.
this app has a base layout which has a logo in the top, a sidebar with navigation buttons and a wrapper, inside this layout I want to have all my app components depending on the navigation buttons i click.

for this I created a bunch of router for each app features, and for the base layout I created a route called app.
all routes with in the app are nested like, app/configuration, app/confirmation, app/updateData, etc...

the problem is, the components are rendered below the app component, not inside it, I want my components to be rendered inside this app component which is suposed to be my app container.

How can I make those components render inside the app container? is this possible? is this the correct approach? any ideas on how to solve this? thanks

Comment: Can you share your code for your app component?

Comment: If you share your code that would be more visible to identify the specific problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to properly nest routes in react, using react router dom v4 and v5.
I was declaring all my routes in a single routes.js file, starting v4 the correct approach is to declare nested routes inside the component .

it was like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path='/' exact component={Home}></Route>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}></Route>
    <Route path='/app' component={AppContainer}></Route>
    <Route path='/app/favorites' component={Favorites}></Route>
    <Route path='/app/jobs' component={Jobs}></Route>
    <Route path='/app/settings' component={Settings}></Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

this way nested components will appear one below de other in a linear way.

now it is like this:

in my root component i have this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path='/' exact component={Home}></Route>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}></Route>
    <Route path='/app' component={AppContainer}></Route>
</BrowserRouter>

at the AppComponent I have the nested routes.
like this:

<Route path={'/app/jobs'} component={Jobs}></Route>
<Route path={'/app/favorites'} component={Favorites}></Route>
<Route path={'/app/confirmation'} component={Confirmation}></Route>
<Route path={'/app/settings'} component={Settings}></Route>

now all components with app/ routes will render inside the app container
```